# Laravel artisan command php artisan make:Import is not defined. Did you mean one of these?

Tags: php, laravel, import, laravel-artisan

How can I resolve the "Command 'make:import' is not defined" error when trying to create an import class for importing an excel file in Laravel?

I'm working on a Laravel project and I need to import an excel file. To accomplish this, I followed these steps:

1. I created the imports folder in the app directory.
2. I ran the command `php artisan make:import BankTransfersHistoryImport --model=BankTransfersHistory`.

However, I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR  Command "make:import" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?
```

```
⇂ make:cast  
 ⇂ make:channel
 ⇂ make:command
 ⇂ make:component
 ⇂ make:controller
 ⇂ make:event
 ⇂ make:exception
 ⇂ make:factory
 ⇂ make:job
 ⇂ make:listener
 ⇂ make:mail
 ⇂ make:middleware
 ⇂ make:migration
 ⇂ make:model
 ⇂ make:notification
 ⇂ make:observer
 ⇂ make:policy
 ⇂ make:provider
 ⇂ make:request
 ⇂ make:resource
 ⇂ make:rule
 ⇂ make:scope
 ⇂ make:seeder
 ⇂ make:test
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has never had an `make:import` command built in by default. I think you may be referring to the [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) package which adds the [import](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/) and [export](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/) commands in `artisan` console.

**Import command:** `php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User`

**Export command:** `php artisan make:export UsersExport --model=User`

---

### Follow the [installations](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html) steps:

- run `composer require maatwebsite/excel`
- Provider and Facede should be auto-discovered

---

### Follow the **["5 minute quick start"](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/):**

Use this command to create an import class `php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User` where **"UsersImport"** will be the class (and file) name, and **User** is the model's name that you want to import. The file will be created in the folder `app/Imports`.

The created file will look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // Here, you must match your model's attributes
        // with the columns in the imported file.
        // Every row will create a new User record in your database
        return new User([
           'name'     => $row[0], // First column
           'email'    => $row[1], // Second column
           'password' => Hash::make($row[2]), // Third column
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your controller you can call this import now:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel; // Laravel excel Facade
use App\Imports\UsersImport; // Import logic

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function import() 
    {
        // the "users.xlsx" is the path to the file you want to import
        // If you're uploading the file with a form
        // you can pass the uploaded file directly with resquest()->file
        // ("file" is the name of the input type "file" in your form)

        Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
        
        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
    }
}
```

If this will be a "public" upload form, remember to always validate any uploaded file by the users for security...

Comment: Yes, you are right,
I want to import an excel file.
so what should I do?

Comment: @yakov I have added more explanations in my answer about how to install the package and a basic import example with the official links of the documentation where you can find more info and examples. Also, you can mark my answer as the "accepted answer"

Answer (score 0):

The `make:import` command does not exist, if what you want is to add a folder to save external files I recommend you use the `php artisan storage:link` command, it creates a symbolic link and the external files are saved there.

you can see the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem

Comment: I must have been looking at an old video that command was there.
Yes, I want to save an Excel file.
Thank you 